# Redirect htaccess .co.uk to .com/en

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need change domain name for a multi-langue web site
domain.co.uk --> domain.com/en

I put this rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domain.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's works but i need more, i want redirect all old url(s) like this :

```
domain.co.uk/page1 --> domain.com/en/page1
domain.co.uk/page2 --> domain.com/en/page2
domain.co.uk/pageXXX --> domain.com/en/pageXXX
```

Can you tell me how i can do this ?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Remove slash here: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]`  and rules should work fine for all requirements.

Comment: It _should_ work  the way you wrote it. Can you give an example of a URL that doesn't work? BTW, in regex _patterns_, get into the habit of escaping literal periods: `^domain\.co\.uk$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option to redirect all pages to the new subdomain is 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Or 
Redirect 301 /page1 http://domain.com/en/page1